# MVC 5 Partial View inside area not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, partial-views

i have MVC 5 project, i created an area, i use ajax to return partialview, when i debug it's working and it goes to the PartialViewResult in the controller, but i doesn't return the partial view however , when i put this prtial view in the _shared but in the main root, it worked.
now i need it to work but from my area

here is the controller

```
public PartialViewResult FillArticleGrid(int CatID)
    {
        try
        {
            ArticleRepository AR = new ArticleRepository();

            return PartialView("_ArticleGrid", AR.GetAllArticles(CatID));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

i'm sure there is nothing wrong with it, it's in the routing but i can't figure this out

Answer (score 0):

Try mentioning your location for partial view explicitly and change your return type from `PartialViewResult` to `ActionResult`

```
return PartialView("~/path to your partial view/_ArticleGrid",AR.GetAllArticles(CatID));
```

when you put it in shared folder it works because by default it'll look for your partial view in shared folder as well

Comment: i will give it a try, then i will tell you

Comment: return PartialView("~/Areas/AreaName/Views/Article/_ArticleGrid", AR.GetAllArticles(CatID));
still not working

Comment: the problem is in the routing, i used to have this problem in MVC 3 but i fixed it, but it's not working for the MVC 5

Comment: what if you change your Return type from PartialViewResult to ActionResult?

Comment: Nice, it worked.
but why is that, is there anyway i can make it work but as PartialViewResult not ActionResult

Comment: I think you can find some answer here http://forums.asp.net/t/1448398.aspx, and may be you want to accept the answer and vote it up if possible ;)

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help

Comment: what the link or the answer?

Comment: yes, i don't want to know the deference between them, all i need to know is how to make some Route changes to make this work